# How to open bootstrap dropdown by external button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've read like a half of the Internet, but nowhere to be find clear example on how to do this. Bunch of "solutions" but nothing works so far..

Here's what I tried:

```
$('#openner').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Nothing works bellow :(
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').click().parent().addClass('open');
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click.bs.dropdown'');
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click().addClass('open');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLuarcdc/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#openner').on('click', function(e){
   $('ul[aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"]').toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLuarcdc/4/

Comment: Ok seems that is working, with one caveat, the "normal" click event on the original toggle button doesn't work.. I need them both working.

Comment: I checked it better, the original toggle button stops working after you click on the external button. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK here is my answer after all tweaking around. I realized that I can't change the  class `.open` on the `div.dropdown` so I decided to use my own class, in this case `.opened`, and all is working.

Code:

```
$('#openner').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Nothing works bellow :(
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').click().parent().addClass('open');
    //$('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click.bs.dropdown'');

    $('.dropdown-toggle').click().parent().toggleClass('opened');
});
```

Here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLuarcdc/6/)